# EKS -nodes fail when launched through a launch template (terraform)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks, launch-template

when i launch the node normally, everything working fine, but when i try to launch it using a launch template, im having connection issues within the cluster.

more specifically, aws-node pod fails with the error:

```
{"level":"info","caller":"/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:225","msg":"timeout: failed to connect service \":50051\" within 5s"}
```

digging through the other posts here, many people seem to point to iam role issues, but my iam role is fine, and besides ive been using the same role to launch many other nodes and they launched succesfully.

here are my terraform files:

```
resource "aws_eks_node_group" "eth-staking-nodes" {
  cluster_name    = aws_eks_cluster.staking.name
  node_group_name = "ethstaking-nodes-testnet"
  node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.nodes.arn

  subnet_ids = [    data.aws_subnet.private-1.id,
    data.aws_subnet.private-2.id
  ]

  scaling_config {
    desired_size = 1
    max_size     = 5
    min_size     = 0
  }

  update_config {
    max_unavailable = 1
  }

  labels = {
    role = "general"
  }

  launch_template {
    version = aws_launch_template.staking.latest_version
    id      = aws_launch_template.staking.id
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.nodes-AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.nodes-AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.nodes-AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly,
  ]
}
```

the launch template:

```
esource "aws_launch_template" "staking" {
  name          = "${var.stage}-staking-node-launch-template"
  instance_type = "m5.2xlarge"
  image_id      = "ami-08712c7468e314435"

  key_name = "nivpem"
  
  block_device_mappings {
    device_name = "/dev/xvda"

    ebs {
      volume_size = 450
      volume_type = "gp2"
    }
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = false
  }

  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.eks-ec2-sg.id]
  user_data = base64encode(templatefile("${path.module}/staking_userdata.sh", {
        password = "********"
      }))

  tags = {
    "eks:cluster-name"   = aws_eks_cluster.staking.name
    "eks:nodegroup-name" = "ethstaking-nodes-testnet"
  }

  tag_specifications {
    resource_type = "instance"

    tags = {
      Name                 = "${var.stage}-staking-node"
      "eks:cluster-name"   = aws_eks_cluster.staking.name
      "eks:nodegroup-name" = "ethstaking-nodes-testnet"
    }
  }
}
```

security group:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "eks-ec2-sg" {
  name        = "eks-ec2-sg-staking-testnet"
  vpc_id      = data.aws_vpc.vpc.id

  ingress {
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = "-1"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = "-1"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "allow_tls"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you configured the networking as per the requirements? For example, are your nodes in a private subnet? If so, is a NAT Gateway deployed? Is there a corresponding Internet Gateway attached to the VPC?

Comment: yes they are. if i launch the node with the same configuration but without the launch template it works perfectly.

Comment: Does the answer you've gotten work for you then?

Comment: No, still can't get the node to work when launching through a launch template.
This issue screams security group issue, as im seeing 'connection refused' among the errors from aws-node pod.
I reviewed the node that got created, and everything from security groups to iam role seems to be correct and should suffice

Comment: Would you mind adding the SG configuration to the question?

Comment: its set to 0.0.0.0/0 for all ports (for testing's sake)
i will add it to the question

Comment: Did you try adding vpc_config with `vpc_config` and `endpoint_public_access` set to true in your `aws_eks_cluster` resource?

Comment: @MohammadTeimoriPabandi that was it! although in my case i was using private subnets, so i had to set the value of endpoint_private_access to true.
thank you very much.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer so you can select it as the correct one :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider adding `vpc_config` with `vpc_config` and `endpoint_public_access` set to `true` in your `aws_eks_cluster` resource. That should make it work since you're using private subnets.